# How to build .wsp file with MSBuild task?

Tags: sharepoint, msbuild

I have the need inside a MSBuild file to build a .wsp file.  How can I do this using native or extended MSBuild tasks?  Please let me know.  I don't want to use the command line or to use MAKECAB.exe

Comment: If you created the project using the SharePoint 2010 or 2013 Solution Template you can run `msbuild /t:package xxx.sln`. The target `Package` creates the `wsp` file. If you want this target executed by default, change the `/Project/@DefaultTargets attribute` from `Build` to `Package`.

Comment: I think that this question shouldn't've been closed. It was tagged correctly by `sharepoint` and any SharePoint developer knew what it was about.

Comment: i agree, however is also asked on sharepoint stack exchange @ http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60888/how-can-i-build-a-wsp-inside-of-a-msbuild-target